# Extend two monitors not working

Tags: multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

Before everything. I had googled a lot and none of the solutions solved my problem.
I had two monitor connected to a `graphic card`. One of them using `VGA cable` and another by `DVI cable`.
My graphic card has only these two outputs.
These are my graphic card and monitors and OS details:

- Monitor One **(SumSung SyncMaster P22700 - 1920x1080 - 21.5" )** connected using **DVI cable**
- Monitor Two **(AOC 931Fwa - 1600x900 - 19")** connected using **VGA cable**
- Graphic Card **(AMD Radeon™ HD 6570 Graphics)**
- OS **(Window 8.1 - 64bit - over PC)**

Now, when I use `Ctrl+P` to `extend` or `duplicate` my monitors it doesn't work. But I can go to the first and second monitor. The whole thing means that the monitors don't work together. But they work separately.

When I try to extend monitors through the control panel this warning appears:

[image]

I have installed the `AMD Catalyst Control` on the pc and when I choose to extend the monitors through that it gives me this warning:

[image]

For additional information on my device manager under the monitors I have two monitors but with the same driver installed I guess. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the drivers but the second monitor (AOC) uses the first one. By the way it's working with this driver installed.

[image]

So, does anyone know what should I do to have extended or duplicated monitors?

Comment: Try using Windows Key + P! I read Ctrl+P and I immediately saw a discrepancy.

Comment: Been there, feel your pain! Try this guy: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/monitors-extended-desktop-3-check/

Answer (score 1):

The Catalyst Control Center is probably mucking things up.

Try this:

- Switch your video driver to the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter driver in Device Manager.  You can do this by selecting your video card, hit **Update Driver**, select **Browse my computer for driver software**, and then select **Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer**.  You should see the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter in the list under all your AMD drivers.
- Completely uninstall everything AMD-related from your computer and then reboot it.
- When your computer comes back up, you should be using the generic Microsoft driver.  At this point, reinstall the AMD driver, but do a custom install and only select the driver itself.  Ignore the extra features (you can add them back in later -- this is just for testing).

Now see if you can extend the displays using nothing but the Windows control panel.  Don't even touch the AMD control panel if you have the option.  If you can get it working like this, then that was the problem.  If not, it may be an issue that the card doesn't support extending to the VGA display.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SyncMaster monitor is installed twice in Device Manager. Can you remove the one that isn't required and then right click on "Black-PC" in Device Manager and select Scan for hardware changes?

Comment: Yeah already done. But SyncMaster will be the system choice for both. I've tried to search the driver of AOC. but didn't find the exact driver of my AOC model which is `AOC 931Fwa` currently The driver installed for the cecond monitor is: `AOC 831w`. But nothing happened.

Comment: Can you change the AOC monitor to a Generic Monitor and set the resolution to 1440 by 900. That seems to be the recommended resolution based on a [manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/625422/Aoc-931fwa.html?page=7#manual) I found on the net.

Comment: I can't change it to Generic Monitor but now both become as SyncMaster again. In control panel, under screen resolution I see both monitors. but when I select second monitor to change the resolution. the resolution jumbox become disabled. wired somehow.

Comment: ok I shifted to the second monitor and put the resolution to 1440 by 900. but still no extend or duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall all the video drivers and monitor drivers but do not delete the drivers. Shut down the system and disconnect the Samsung monitor. Start again and let windows install the drivers automatically. Then connect the Samsung. Go into display setting and do a detect. Go for the recommended resolution, apply and then try to extend the screen. If that doesn't work, see if you can set the VGA monitor to be the default display and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you if youre problem is similar.

****My problem****- I'm using my Dell 15 5567 laptops. but still wanted to extend to a sec to a second AOC gaming monitor & . . .it would mirror but not extend.

****Answer****
A few months had gone by and then I remembered that I decreased my laptops resolution to 1080, I found the correct and matched them & it then extended of course lol

Duh me lol GL!Xp